# Magento 2 marketplace submission issue

Tags: magento2, plugin, marketplace

I have update one my extension to the marketplace.

But I am getting error “Class doesn't exist” error but my class is already there.

My di.xml is below.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout">
        <plugin name="custom_layout_load" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Plugin\CustomLayout" />
    </type>
```

My Plugin CustomLayout.php is below.

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout;
/**
 * Description of SalesFormLayout
 *
 * @author dharmendra
 */
class CustomLayout
{
    const CUSTOM_LAYOUT_HANDLE = 'custome_layout';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * LayoutPlugin constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param Layout $layout
     * @param $response
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterAddDefaultHandle(Layout $layout, $response)
    {
        $fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
        if ($fullActionName == 'layout_action') {
            $layout->addHandle(self::CUSTOM_LAYOUT_HANDLE);
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Still Marketplace throw error class doesn't exist.
I will stuck with the issue if any one know the solution please give.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bro, Plugins are inherited. Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout implements Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface

Comment: Try this code...

Comment: <type name="Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface">
        <plugin name="custom_layout_load" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Plugin\CustomLayout" />
    </type>

Comment: /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php

Comment: Issue is not that which class inherited. But issue is that Class doesn't exist but I have that class define and it's working with local

Comment: It's marketplace issue not in coding

Comment: @DharmendraJadav same issue I have. have you solved? Any clue? why this happening

Comment: @bojjaiah not getting any luck

Comment: @DharmendraJadav Have you not solved?

Comment: @Bojjaiah yes still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run below commands to regenerate class.

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: I have already run that all commands.

Comment: didn't getting any issue with the commands.

Comment: You can check with this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136910/main-critical-plugin-class-doesnt-exist

Comment: It can't help becuase I have already checked it's working fine but issue with only when I uploaded it into the marketplace.